# Angular 4 - pass data into components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm really confused, I'm trying to inject data from one component to another in **Angular 4**, it seems like the data passes but it won't be shown, I will go straight to the example code:

**board.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'game-board',
  template: `<card [init]="name"></card>`,
})

export class BoardComponent  {
  name: string = 'this is the card name';
}
```

**Card.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'card',
      template: `<div class="card-container"> 
                    CARD - {{strength}}
                 </div>`,
    })
    export class CardComponent  {
      @Input('init') strength: string;
    }
```

I would except the outcome to be "CARD - this is the card name"
but it's just "CARD - ".

Here is how the element looks like (chrome dev tools, ignore the gap between 'CARD -' and ''):

[image]

So I see that the injection worked and the `"this is the card name"` passed, but for some reason `strength` is undefined.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Did you mean Angular 2 instead of Angular 4. Version 2 is 5he latest version of Angular not 4!

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn No it's Angular 4 that has been released few days ago, look here: http://angularjs.blogspot.co.il/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html

But if you see any mistake I made that wouldn't work on Angular 2 as well feel free to suggest!

Comment: Have you tried another browser or passing a bare string to the card.init attribute instead of BoardComponent.name or changing name of the init attribute to something else? The code looks good, so I'm just looking for some hints.

Comment: @JánHalaša Yes, I've also tried from the "index.html" doing "<card [init]="hello"></card> and I get the same results.

Comment: Can you please post a plunker for the same as it works for me

Comment: CardComponent is imported, otherwise it wouldn't render "CARD - "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the main component is defined in your bootstrap attribute in the ngModule definition and that both components are defined as declarations.
Should look something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ BoardComponent, CardComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ BoardComponent ]
})
```

Only the main component should be defined in the bootstrap array and both in the declarations array.

Comment: The documentation confused me and you are right, I've added "CardComponent" in both 'declarations' & 'bootstrap', it caused the CardComponent to be overwritten with nothing. Thank you.